# Using JavaScript how to convert 1524801600000 to new Date(YYYY,MM,DD)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am getting date as string `1524801600000`. I want to convert it as new `Date(2018, 4, 27)`.

How can I do  that using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date in case you need to format it later

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it to Date Constructor.

> (+) Unary operator. Attempts to convert the operand to a number, if it is not already. more details here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

```js
var temp="1524801600000";
var p=new Date(+temp)
console.log(p)
```

Comment: The OP said it was a string

Comment: Be sure to call `parseInt` if the value being passed to `Date` is a string, as OP specified

Comment: @JimRhodes updated with string

Comment: it seems the OP is new to this language judging by his question. It would be nice to explain to him what you are doing with `+temp`